# Custom session id generation implement UuidGenerator

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, glassfish

i want to set cutom class for session id generation(Custom session id generation) in glassfish server , from my search till now i found that custom class should implement "com sun enterprise util uuid.UuidGenerator" class

so i tried to create my own class as

```
import com.sun.enterprise.util.uuid;
public class Customsessionid implements UuidGenerator {


    public UuidGeneratorImpl() 
    {
    }

    public String generateUuid() {
        return UuidUtil.generateUuid();
    }

    public String generateUuid(Object obj) {
        return UuidUtil.generateUuid(obj);
    }

}
```

but import gives error as package not found

can anybody help me implementing UuiGenerator class please provide code for sutom session id generation if you can thanks in advance

Comment: Java already has a uuid generator.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis OP is asking about **custom** uuid generator.

Comment: @ay89 Yeah, but I'm commenting that he shouldn't try to create one.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis yeah java has one but for my project ,i need to use new algorithm for session id generation so i need to implement custom

Answer (score 0):

You can't import a package in the way you tried. You have to use a wildcard or import a specific class:

Try this:

```
import com.sun.enterprise.util.uuid.*;
```

A detailed explanation of packages and imports can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.1) (especially Example 7.5.1-3. **No Import of a Subpackage**)

Comment: package com.sun.enterprise.util.uuid does not exist error for this ya here i made typing mistek in my code i am doing as 
import com.sun.enterprise.util.uuid.UuidGenerator;