# set custom session id java (apache tomcat)

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I want to set custom session id for my web application ,I have alogorithm to generate session id my web application should use that algo for generating session id.
  please suggest me how cam i set my algorithm as session id generation in tomcat..

session Manager --> i tried this but it provide complete session behaviour modification control ,i just want to set session id as per my algo no session behaviour changes

Implementing com.sun.entrprises.uui.uuidgenerator ---> tried this also but not able to understand exactly how to do this

please suggest me simplest solution just to set my algo as session generation algorithm

Note: you might suggest not to do it but i needed it for my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager should do what you want. 
Do something like this:

```
public class MySessionManager extends StandardManager {

    @Override
    protected synchronized String generateSessionId() { 
        String sessionId = <Your session id generation algo>;
        return sessionId;
    }
}
```

After you have your session manager, follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8684682/1686330).

Comment: Thank You , I did above code my algo to generate sessionid ,but in Context.xml when i set
 <Manager className="tomcatdata.MySessionManager"> gives error
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tomcatdata.MySessionManager
i put MysessionManger class in my webapplication /Src/tomcatdata/MySessionManager

Comment: Looks as if tomcat cannot find your session manager impl. Have you deployed your custom sessionmanager to $CATALINA_HOME? Also look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10935726/1686330

Comment: btw: I've seen your other question ( http://stackoverflow.com/q/15933744/1686330 ) where you mention glass fish. I'm not sure if this works for glass fish. For Glassfish you might look at http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18994 .

Comment: Thanks alot for solving my problem :)

Comment: which dependency is needed to import StandardManager?

Comment: @jpganz18 Depends on your tomcat version, e.g. this one: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.55/org/apache/catalina/session/StandardManager.java

Comment: @DirkLachowski I guess for Tomcat 7.0.82 `StandardManager` is modified and not having any method like `generateSessionId()`. now We have to implement `org.apache.catalina.SessionIdGenerator`, is this correct?