# can I specify the JSESSION id value for a session?

Tags: java, spring, jsessionid

I was wondering if is possible to override the bean that returns the JSESSIONID (or whoever creates it) and return the id I want? like happens with the CSRF that you can specify the repository?

Any idea?

Comment: Short answer, no. Session creation is left to the servlet container and isn't under control of Spring. So unless you change something in your servlet container (replace core parts of it) you won't be able to do this.

Comment: Like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947407/set-custom-session-id-java-apache-tomcat ?